# How to/possible to add fingerprint login to mobile wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, single-sign-on, biometrics

We are creating an intranet Wordpress site and using Microsoft Azure AD for SSO - This site will only be accessibly to internal staff. For better user experience, we would also like to attach fingerprint login to anyone that is logging in using their mobile device - is this possible? How?

I've searched everywhere online, maybe I'm not searching for the right thing - any help towards the right direction is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add your code to check it or google it :-)

Comment: I'm sorry I do not understand your response..
Add what code or google what..